# How to shadow an interface variable with an instanced variable

Tags: java, interface

I'm having some trouble shadowing an interface variable with an instanced variable. I know how to do this by overriding the method and manually assigning the variable within the method, but can't figure out how to use the instanced variable of whatever object invokes the method.

```
public interface ShakesHands {

    static final String name = "Gabe";

    public void shakeHands (ShakesHands other);
}

class Student implements ShakesHands{

    String name;

    @Override
    public void shakeHands(ShakesHands other) {
        String othersName = other.name;
        System.out.println(name + " shook " + othersName + "'s hand.");
    }
}

class Parent implements ShakesHands{

    String name;

    @Override
    public void shakeHands(ShakesHands other) {
        String othersName = other.name;
        System.out.println(name + " shook " + othersName + "'s hand.");
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.name = "Bob";

        Parent parent1 = new Parent();
        parent1.name = "Sally";

        student1.shakeHands(parent1);
    }
}
```

This code will output "Bob shook Gabe's hand." Is there any way I can stop it from referencing the interface name "Gabe", and instead reference the instanced name "Sally" so that i get "Bob shook Sally's hand"?

Comment: Why does `ShakesHands` have a `name` in the first place?

Comment: I would use accessors (setters and getters) rather than accessing a field directly.  Your example is pretty questionable; I can't think of a valid use for this coding style.

Comment: If i don't assign a name to ShakesHands, I get a "name cannot be resolved or is not a field" error

Comment: Then don't try to access a `name` field on a `ShakesHands` reference value. You're doing things backwards.

Comment: Use methods as @markspace recommended.

Comment: And a hint why you *need* to use methods: there is no polymorphy for fields/variables and that's what you need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside questions on coding style and clean code, here is why you code always prints "... shook Gabe's hand.":

The method implementation of shaking hands references the "name" from a ShakesHands instance, not of one of the implementing classes. As the only "name" from a ShakesHands is "in scope" here, you always end up using the static variable with value "Gabe".

It is actually better for the compiler to always use the static variable value, instead of using the implementing class's variable (if such variable exists). The data type of in the derived or implementing class is not required to be the same as in the superclass / interface, so you could have ShakeHand's name to be of a different type than the Student's name.

Example:

```
public interface ShakesHands {

    String name = "Gabe";

    public void shakeHands(ShakesHands other);
}

class Student implements ShakesHands {

    Integer name = Integer.valueOf(0);

    @Override
    public void shakeHands(ShakesHands other) {
        System.out.println(name.getClass().getSimpleName() + " (in this class) with value "+name+" vs. " + other.name.getClass().getSimpleName()+" (in other class) with value "+other.name);
    }
}
```

For my example invocation the printet text was "Integer (in this class) with value 7 vs. String (in other class) with value Gabe".

Another thing: even though in all implementations of your program there is a "name" variable in the implementing class: at compile time the compiler does not know if that is still the case at runtime. Your JAR might be used in another program that defined a "UnnamedShakesHand" class (without a "name" variable). What should happen then? What should happen to your code if the implementing class defined "name" with another class? Should it throw a "ClassCastException" because of your "String othersName = other.name;" instruction?

**To cut the long story short:
introduce a "String getName()" method in the "ShakesHands" interface.** Each of the implementing classes can return their name's variable value and everything is fine.

Comment: Also, follow the coding conventions. The constant should have been spelled `NAME`, and the confusion would have gone away.